# What is the genre defined by getting as far as possible along an infinite level called?

Tags: terminology

I am interested in making a mobile game in the style of an infinite hallway. Like *Jetpack Joyride* where the background moves and you just steer your guy up or down to avoid stuff. You can have a glimpse [here on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OBWtXm1_a6U) of what it looks like.

I have never made one before, in fact, I have no idea what that genre is called...

What is this genre called?

Comment: A simple Google search for "jetpack joyride genre" would have turned up the answer.

Comment: ok, fine. Ya got me... I am still interested in how to make one though...

Comment: @JuddGledhill "how to get started" is out of the scope of this site. You could visit forums like gamedev.net for more help regarding this.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt - it is? I kinda thought it was the right place to be! Let me check the rules...

Comment: @JuddGledhill [Here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), "_how to get started making a game_".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with game _development_ as such, irrespective of what the OP may or may not _intend_ to do with the answer to this question.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer I disagree; To me this seems like a valid question, and it's certainly more relevant to game developers than the general population. One could argue that it would be a somewhat better fit on [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/), but I don't think it's *blatantly* off-topic here, and the [migration guidelines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) suggest to avoid migrating answered questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The genre is a infinite runner. Or an endless side scrolling runner.

The goal of the game is to get as far as possible.

Generally, this kind of game has it's content randomly generated as the player advances. The player advances automatically, while s/he has to perform some other actions to 'survive' as long as possible.

One of the most popular early games of this genre was [Canabalt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canabalt), where the player only had the option to jump at the most appropriate time.

The genre has evolved since then.

---

"How to start making one" is really to broad for this site, but here is the tip of the iceberg:

You would need:

- a 2d platormer game architecture with physics and collision detection
- a live content generation algorithm (as opposed to offline like we see in games like Starbound or Elite: Dangerous). Each run is different.